# Adding values to array in another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

Let's say I have an array like this:

```
var someData = [ // count: 5

    [ something, something, something ], // count: 3
    [ something ], // count: 1
    [ something, something, something, something ],  // count: 4
    [ ], // count: 0
    [ something, something ] // count: 2
];
```

I need to make array like this:

```
var myArray = [];

var firstCount = someData.lenght; // count: 5

for( a = 0; a < firstCount; a++ ) {

    allObjects[a] = firstObject;


    var secondCount = someData[a].lenght; // each has different

    for( b = 0; b < secondCount; b++ ) {

        allObjects[a] = secondObject; 
    }
}
```

---

**How Im expecting it to be:**

```
allObjects = [

    [ firstObject, secondObject, secondObject ], // count: 3
    [ firstObject ], // count: 1
    [ firstObject, secondObject, secondObject, secondObject ], // count:  4
    [ ], // count: 0
    [ firstObject, secondObject ], // count: 2
];
```

---

I might have made few *(format)* mistakes in this example but I hope that my goal is clear - **I need to push objects to array of objects that is already in array** but it seems to replace the value instead adding new value into it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, but generally `array[i] = 'value'` overwrites the value, if you want to add you either `push()` or `unshift()`

Comment: Please make a specific example, without `something` and `secondObject`, including an example function call.

Comment: the = sign will assign your object to the variable (allObjects[a]), you want to push it onto the array `allObjects[a].push(secondObject)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be wrong, but from your expected result, it seems that you want to push it to second index of array. In that case, you can change your inner for loop to be

```
var secondCount = someData[a].lenght; // each has different

    for( b = 1; b < secondCount; b++ ) {

        allObjects[a][b] = secondObject; 
    }
```

Note the changes in b = 1 and allObjects[a][b]